# Is it possible to write the following lisp macro as a function?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I'm reading [Paul Graham's *ANSI Common Lisp*](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html). In the chapter about macros he shows the following example:

```
(defmacro in (obj &rest choices)
  (let ((insym (gensym)))
   `(let ((,insym ,obj))
      (or ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (c) `(eql ,insym ,c))
                    choices)))))
```

(Returns true if the first argument is equal to any of the other arguments)

He holds that it can't be written as a function. Wouldn't this function have the same functionality?

```
(defun in (obj &rest choices)
  (reduce (lambda (x y)
            (or x (eql y obj)))
          choices
          :initial-value nil))
```

The difference I see is that the macro will only evaluate arguments till it finds an eql argument. Is that it?

Comment: That's rather a large "Is that it?". If someone said "I can give you an `IF` that's not a macro but just a function! (But it always evaluates both branches.)", would you say "Is that it?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is, that the macro version evaluates the arguments lazily (it expands into an OR) stopping if a match is found. This cannot be achieved with a function, since a funcall will always evaluate all arguments first.

Answer (score 3):

```
> (macroexpand '(in 42
                    (long-computation-1)
                    (long-computation-2)
                    (long-computation-3)))

(LET ((#:G799 42))
  (OR (EQL #:G799 (LONG-COMPUTATION-1))
      (EQL #:G799 (LONG-COMPUTATION-2))
      (EQL #:G799 (LONG-COMPUTATION-3))))
```

To get the same effect you would need to write:

```
(defun in (obj &rest choices)
  (reduce (lambda (x y)
             (or x (eql (funcall y) obj)))
          choices
          :initial-value nil))
```

and use it this way:

```
(in 42
    (function long-computation-1)
    (function long-computation-2)
    (function long-computation-3))
```